# How is a page produced in the output routine?

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

Compare this

```
\nonstopmode
\tracingonline=1

\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen

\output={\shipout\vbox{
  \unvbox255
  \showlists
}}

\nopagenumbers
\noindent A
\bye
```

and this

```
\nonstopmode
\tracingonline=1

\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen

\newbox\pagebox
\let\oldshipout\shipout
\def\shipout{\global\let\shipout\oldshipout\afterassignment\myboat\setbox\pagebox=}
\def\myboat{\aftergroup\myship}
\def\myship{\setbox\pagebox=\vbox{
  \unvbox\pagebox
  \showlists
}\shipout\box\pagebox}

\nopagenumbers
\noindent A
\bye
```

In the second trace we have some additional output compared to that of the first example, namely:

- Additional output of the second example before identical output of both examples:

```
\vbox(0.0+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 14.0fil
.\glue -22.5
.\hbox(8.5+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 469.75499fil
..\vbox(8.5+0.0)x0.0
..\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
\vbox(643.20255+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 633.20255fill
```

- Additional output of the second example after identical output of both examples:

```
\glue(\baselineskip) 24.0
\hbox(0.0+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 469.75499fil
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
```

where `643.20255` equals 8.9in (i.e., `11 - 1 - 1 - 0.1`) and `469.75499` equals 6.5in (i.e., `8.5 - 1 - 1`)

The question is about this additional output - what does it mean and why does it appear in the second example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case you are just seeing box255, in the second case you are using the plain tex output routine and hooking into `\shipout` so you are seeing

```
\shipout\vbox{\makeheadline\pagebody\makefootline}%
```

and the extra boxes you see are the headline and footline which are white because of `\nopagenumbers` but the box and glue structure is still there.

Comment: What do all that glues in the headline mean?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko it's directly the output of plain.tex, no computation is involved, for example the headline is defined by `\def\makeheadline{\vbox to\z@{\vskip-22.5\p@
  \line{\vbox to8.5\p@{}\the\headline}\vss}\nointerlineskip}` and `\the\headline` is empty in this case, so you get exactly the boxes and glue that you show.

Comment: Can't be a box (in this case the footline box) just empty, without the need for glue in it?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko you can make such a box but plain tex doesn't: the footline is `\def\makefootline{\baselineskip24\p@\lineskiplimit\z@\line{\the\footline}}` it doesn't not make the box just because `\the\footline` is empty

Comment: If we want to remove footline completely, `\nopagenumbers` is not enough. What else should be done to suppress that `\glue(\baselineskip) 24.0`?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko you show that in your first code, write an output routine that does not add it.